# Arduino - Serial Communication not working

Tags: c, arduino

I'm having problem getting in to the second Serial.available loop of my code located in the Package. Please, let me know, if you see anything wrong with the code.
[Arduino Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYUO0.png)

Inputs:
 1. "Package" -> I get +1 back from the Serial Monitor
 2. "5&12!23!34!59!70!" -> I get 0 back from the Serial Monitor. For this one, I'm supposed to see, 5 12 23 34 59 70

Please, let me know, if you see anything wrong in this code and why is the Serial.available not functional in the Package?

```
String incoming;
String readIncoming; 
int i=0;
typedef struct {
  int npins;
  int addr[512];
}
measureList;
measureList list; 
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("Serial conection started");
    incoming = ""; list.npins = 6; 
}
void loop() {
   while(Serial.available() > 0) {
   incoming = Serial.readString();

  if(incoming == "HI")        {  Serial.println("Steven"); }
  if(incoming == "SampleAll") {  SampleAll();             }
  if(incoming == "Package")   { Serial.println("+1"); Package(); }
  }
}
void Package(void)
{
  while(1)
{ 

if(Serial.available()>0 & i<= list.npins)

 {
        char recieved = Serial.read(); 

 if (recieved != '&' & i == 0){incoming = incoming + recieved;}

 if (recieved == '&' & i == 0){list.npins = incoming.toInt(); Serial.println(list.npins); incoming=""; i = 1;}

  if (recieved != '!' & recieved != '&' & i > 0){incoming = incoming + recieved; }

  if (recieved == '!' & recieved != '&' & i > 0){ list.addr[i] = incoming.toInt(); Serial.println(list.addr[i]);incoming = "";  i = i + 1;} 

 if (i == list.npins) {break;}
  }
}
}
```

Comment: please post your code, not image of it

Comment: also, one trivial thing: Boolean and is `&&`. Logical / bitwise and is `&`.

Comment: Done. Please review